# What can cause gnome-shell/gnome-tweaks to fail?

Tags: gnome-shell, python3, gnome-tweak-tool

Ubuntu 18.10, python3.7.1, GNOME Tweaks, etc. installed.

Could installing a source build of python3.7.1 cause this issue? And how to debug?

I have tried a number of different ways to repair gnome-shell problems to no effect.
From the google-chrome extensions plugin: I see:

> Unable to locate GNOME Shell settings or version. Make sure it is installed and running.

And if I try:

```
/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/gnome-shell
```

I see:

```
  File "/usr/bin/gnome-shell", line 1
  SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xfc' in file /usr/bin/gnome-shell on line 2, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

And attempting to launch 'GNOME Tweaks' fails:

```
   sudo /usr/bin/gnome-tweaks
   (gnome-tweaks:25453): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 15:29:44.666: g_dbus_proxy_new_sync: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed
   WARNING : Shell not installed or running
   WARNING : Error detecting shell
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gtweak/tweaks/tweak_group_shell_extensions.py", line 217, in __init__
       raise Exception("Shell not running or DBus service not available")
   ...
```

And:

```
sudo /usr/bin/gnome-tweaks
```

Gives:

```
(gnome-tweaks:25453): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 15:29:44.666: g_dbus_proxy_new_sync: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed
WARNING : Shell not installed or running
WARNING : Error detecting shell
Traceback .....
```

Purging and reinstalling gnome-shell and 'GNOME Tweaks' does not help.  And

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

didn't help.

I also tried:

```
sudo gnome-shell --replace
```

which caused the display to blink, but didn't help either.

**Any thoughts?**

Comment: I just updated and got the same error :-(